# execute a.out at a specific date/time on linux

Tags: linux, time

I need to start "a.out" at a specific date/time.
for example, I want to start "a.out" at 12:10:30 PM very exactly.
Any Idea is appreciated !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what `cron` and/or `at` are for.

Since `cron` only has a one minute resolution, you may want to set up a script that runs at 12:09.

This script would then go into a tight loop checking the date and time until it was exactly 12:10:30, then run your "real" code.

So, your `cron` entry would be:

```
9 12 * * * /mydir/myscript
```

and `/mydir/myscript` would be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ $(date +%H%M%S) -lt 121030 ; do
    sleep 1
done
/mydir/myexecutable
```

That's if you want it running many days at the same time of day. For a one-shot execution, you can still use the script, but use `at` to run it (the time string is `YYYYMMDDhhmm`):

```
at -f /mydir/myscript -t 201212311209
```

Alternatively, if your `at` is advanced enough, it may allow sub-minute specification in the `-t` option so that your wrapper job is not hanging around too long (time string of `YYYYMMDDhhmm.ss`):

```
at -f /mydir/myscript -t 201212311210.25
```

Comment: `cron` is **not** designed to run a one-shot command. See my post

Comment: @sputnick, I saw date/time in the question but it was inconsistent since only a time was specified in the example. I've since edited the answer to allow for both possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

This simple as :

```
at 1210 <<< "sleep 30; /path/to/a.out"
```

`at` command is designed especially to run a command at a particular time. `cron` is different, it is designed for repeated tasks.

See `man 1 at`